# Java integration test reusable base setup

Tags: java, integration-testing

In my application I have a couple of integration tests which all do the following:

- Set up the application context
- Create test database
- Populate the test database with data

It takes time to always do these three initial steps for each integration test. I want them to be some sort of base for all integration tests.
Does anyone have experience with this and can point me in the right direction with articles, tools, threads and so on?

Thankful for any help!

/Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option here is to create a base class with the `@BeforeClass` method so whenever you need to reuse it - just extend it by your test classes.

Another option is to use [org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html). It provides you with a possibility to hook up your code on different events e.g. test started, test finished etc:

```
class TestListener extends RunListener {
    @Override
    public void testRunStarted(Description description) throws Exception {
        // Called before any test has started
    }

    @Override
    public void testRunFinished(Result result) throws Exception {
        // Called when all tests have finished
    }

    @Override
    public void testStarted(Description description) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void testFinished(Description description) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void testFailure(Failure failure) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void testAssumptionFailure(Failure failure) {
    }

    @Override
    public void testIgnored(Description description) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

You can use that even with Maven's surefire (unit tests) plugin or failsafe plugin (integration tests) by adding following code into plugin configuration:

```
<properties>
  <property>
    <name>listener</name>
    <value>com.your.awersome.TestListener</value>
  </property>
</properties>
```

This solution is more flexible but IMHO less obvious compared to the first option if you need to do it for only one project.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [@BeforeAll](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/BeforeAll.html) of Junit5.

As the documentation says, @BeforeAll is used to signal that the annotated method should be executed before all tests in the current test class.

So with that approach, all database setup can be done once for class instead of once for every single method.

Comment: But I have several test classes and I want a base for all of them

Comment: @RichardSilvertass you can create an abstract class with `@BeforeAll` logic, and then just inherit your classes

Comment: Exactly, you can do what @dehasi says